# about argparse when using fabric

Tags: python, fabric, argparse

I am new to python & fabric.
I have a python module module1.py which would like to take in a command parameter, we use argparse inside the module1.py to require a command line parameter.
But we are trying to run the whole program through fabric, if I directly specify the command line when running through fab, I got

```
mycode.py: error: argument --config_yaml is required
```

How could I pass the argument through fab?

Thanks!

Comment: Why is this question tagged torando? In any case, this is caused by fab (which I am not familiar with) not passing command line arguments through to `module1.py`, not with python or `argparse`

Answer (score 1):

From what i can see from here:

https://github.com/fabric/fabric/blob/master/fabric/main.py#L340
https://github.com/fabric/fabric/blob/master/fabric/main.py#L619

You CAN'T do it. You can't add things to `env_options` before main.py runs, your code inside `fabfile.py` will run after `main()` has already been processed.

You can however do this:

Rename `fabfile.py` -> whatever you want as long as its not `fabric.py`. I called mine `fabricc.py`

```
from fabric.state import env_options, make_option

env_options.append(make_option('--myconfig', dest='config_file', default='default.ini'))

from fabric import main
from fabric.api import task, env

@task
def do_something():
    print('config file: {}'.format(env.config_file))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main.find_fabfile = lambda x: __file__
    main.main()
```

now run it:

```
$ python fabricc.py do_something
config file: default.ini

Done.
```

or..

```
$ python fabricc.py do_something --myconfig=somethinelse.ini
config file: somethinelse.ini

Done.
```

Word of warning DO NOT call it `--config` -- this is a builtin param.

With this you still enjoy everything you still love about `fabric` and nothing has changed.

```
$ python fabricc.py do_something --help
Usage: fab [options] <command>[:arg1,arg2=val2,host=foo,hosts='h1;h2',...] ...

Options:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -d NAME, --display=NAME
...
  -z INT, --pool-size=INT
                        number of concurrent processes to use in parallel mode
  --myconfig=CONFIG_FILE
```

PS. i dont suggest you do the fabric override to handle it manually. Im just showing you it can be done. (the reason i dont condone this is: compatibility. If the version changes tomorrow this *might* break) best to use the product how the author meant it to be used.

====================================================================

Also, fabric is meant to be a fancy orm builder -- for lack of a better word. You cannot have command line arguments on a per-task-basis, it wasnt design to work like that. BUT it was designed to take in task-function arguments:

```
@task
def do_something(file=None):
    print('config file: {}'.format(file or 'default.ini'))

$ fab dosomething:test
config file: override.ini

Done.
```

and that is what fabric was created to do.

its meant to be used like this:

```
@task
def environment(box_env=None):
    ...

@task
def deploy(branch='master'):
    ...

@task
def provision(recreate_if_existing=False, start_nignx=True):
    ...

fab evironment:dev deploy:development

fab evironment:dev provision:True,False
```

all together.

```
fab evironment:dev provision deploy:development
```

Answer (score 0):

I know `argparse`, but not `fabric`.  From the error is looks like your script defines a '--config_yaml' `argparse` argument (and makes it 'required').  But `fabric` apparently also uses that argument name.

I don't know if `fabric` also uses `argparse`.  But it is common for programs like that to strip off the commandline arguments that it expects, and pass the rest on to your code.

Do you need to use `--config_yaml` in your script?  And why is it set to `required=True`?  `argparse` allows you to specify a `required` parameter, but ideally flagged arguments like this are optional.  If not given they should have a reasonable default.

---

I see a `--config=...` argument in the `fabric` API, but not a `--config_yaml`.

I wonder if this section about per-task arguments is relevant

http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.10/usage/fab.html#per-task-arguments

It sounds like you need to add the task name to the argument.  `fabric` doesn't just pass all unknown arguments to the task (which is what I was assuming above).  But I don't have `fabric` installed, so can't test it.

Comment: under fabric, if I specify --config_yaml, it will complain cannot recognize this flag :(

Comment: Is the fabric doc link relevant?

Comment: I think it's not really, the arguments mentioned in that file should be specified at the task level. But I was thinking Module1.py could be reused by other files, it should be able to take it's own parameter (no matter used in which program)

Comment: Sounds like we are both guessing as to how `fabric` invokes your code.